# Pandas cumulative sum based on column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have such a data frame:

ID point, survey date, and a precipitation value for each day of 2018 (+365 columns, 1 for each day).

```
|id|survey_date|2018/01/01|2018/01/02|...|2018/12/30|2018/12/31|
|--|-----------|----------|----------|---|----------|----------|
|01| 2018/06/06|         6|          |   |         2|          |
|02| 2018/05/25|         1|         3|   |         2|         6|
|03| 2018/06/06|         4|         1|   |          |         1|
|xx| 2018/06/06|         6|          |   |         2|          |
```

Data frame:

```
           0    1         2    3    4     5     6     7     8          9    \
0     01/08/18   18  45763046  0.7  2.0   7.5   2.3   1.3   0.0   0.000000   
1     31/05/18    3  31902138  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0  14.8  25.8   3.000000   
2     11/05/18    2  34882144  1.4  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  15.6   4.900000   
3     30/05/18    2  44322920  3.6  4.1   6.0  29.7   5.4   0.0   0.000000   
4     29/08/18    2  31102104  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0  17.1  24.6   7.500000  
...  
           358   359  360  361  362  363  364   365  366  367  
0     ...  2.9   7.9  2.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   2.2  1.4  0.0  
1     ...  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  
2     ...  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  
3     ...  5.0  33.1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  10.1  1.7  0.0  
4     ...  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0
```

`Column[0] -> survey date`

`Column[2] -> point_id`

`Columns[3-367] -> Dates form 01/01 to 31/12`

Expected output:

`Column [368] -> Sum of values= from survey_date to 30 days before in each row.`

Example: if in the `point_id = 1` the survey date is `01/08/2018 (column order 217)`  I want to add to the last column the sum of columns from `06/07/2018 (column[187])` to `01/08/2018 (column[217])`

I would like to have a new column with the cumulative precipitation value for the 30 days prior to the survey date for each id. To do this I suppose I have to create a loop in which I identify the value of the survey date field and add the sum of the values of the columns from that date to the previous 30, but I can't figure out how to do it. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: It is ambiguous (and tedious) to work with text in this case. Can you please provide **minimal** input data as DataFrame constructor or dictionary? Also provide the expected output

Comment: I have tried to explain it a little more graphically. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it right the primary key (combination that makes an observation unique) of your table is id-survey_date. I'll start by creating a DataFrame with

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(40) 
cols = pd.date_range(start="2018-01-01", end="2018-12-31")
ids = ["01", "02", "03", "04"]
survey_date = ["2018-06-06", "2018-06-06", "2018-05-25", "2018-06-06"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": ids, "survey_date": survey_date})
for col in cols:
  df[col.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")] = np.random.uniform(1, 10, 4)
```

Since I've created with strings the `survey_date` field I'll convert to datetime with `df["survey_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["survey_date"])`. Now I'll change a bit the format of the Dataframe to make my life easier

```py
df_new_format = df.melt(id_vars=["id", "survey_date"], var_name="reference_date", value_name="ppt")
```

Now using `df_new_format.head()` we can see that the Dataframe looks like this.

[image: output from df_new_format.head()]

Now that we have in a row manner the `reference_date` and `ppt` for each `id`-`survey_date` combination we can use groupby with a custom function to get the sum in the desired interval.

Let's first create the custom function that will have as its inputs a grouped Dataframe and the number of days (in case we want to use a number that isn't 30)

```py
def sum_30_day(df_group, days):
  # condition used to select interval we want
  cond = (df_group["reference_date"].between(df_group["survey_date"]-pd.Timedelta(days=days), df_group["survey_date"]))
  return df_group.loc[cond, "ppt"].sum() # returning the sum of ppt in the right interval
```

Now we can get the sum of `ppt` for each `id`-`survey_date` with

```py
sum_30_day = df_new_format.groupby(["id", "survey_date"]).apply(sum_30_day, 30) # this is a series
# In case you want to merge results with the original Dataframe 
sum_30_day.name = "sum_ppt"
df = df.merge(sum_30_day , how='left', left_on=["id", "survey_date"], right_index=True)
```